# Casting and melting data

Tags: java, reshape

I would like to know if Java supports "casting and melting" of data somehow. By "casting and melting" I mean "reshaping" data in the way that the R package reshape ( or reshape2) does.

So I have a SQL query that returns the following ( in a ResultSet ) :

```
---------------------
|Id | Key    | Value|
---------------------
|1  | Name   | John |
|1  | Gender | Male | 
|1  | Country| U.S  |
|2  | Name   | Tom  |
|2  | Gender | Male |
|2  | Country| Cuba |
---------------------
```

I want to reshape this data so that I can get this :

```
------------------------
|Id|Name|Gender|Country|
------------------------
|1 |John|Male  |U.S    |
|2 |Tom |Male  |Cuba   |
------------------------
```

How do Java programmers achieve this transformation ?

Comment: Copy from one array to the other.

Comment: (Of course, there may be ways to do it as a part of the SQL query, but that has nothing to do with Java.)

Comment: `for(i...) for(j...) ar1[i][j] = ar2[j][i];`?

Comment: define: reshape - array resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly.  R is more focused on data while Java is more of a general purpose language and lacks some of the various specific functions.  You can either program something yourself; or use a "ETL" (Extract, Transform, Load) tool such as Kettle http://kettle.pentaho.com/

Answer (score 1):

This can be usually done by using an [*adapter design pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) which takes care of encapsulating the data and provide a different interface to the fields.

Otherwise you could just create new objects by vising your starting ones and converting the fields in the format you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Let SQL does it for you. Assuming your table is named "foo":

```
Select name.id, name.value, gender.value, country.value 
-- 3 views of 'foo', one for names, 2nd for gender, 3rd for country
from foo as name, foo as gender, foo as country 
-- restricting each view to its purpose
where name.key='Name' and gender.key='Gender' and country.key='Country'
-- joining the 3 views together
and name.id=gender.id and name.id=country.id
```

Comment: in many cases, this is an easy solution and it should be followed; one of the disadvantages of using this solution is that when new attributes are needed (in this example: Age, Relationship Status , Occupation etc.) somebody has to **manually** update the view ;